# Per-fragment lighting system behaves like ambient lighting system

Tags: opengl, shaders, lighting, fragment-shader, per-pixel

This is the relevant section of my fragment shader

```
  varying vec3 normal;
  varying vec3 halfv;
  ...
    vec4 color = ambient * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
    vec3 n = normalize(normal);

    float nl = max(dot(n, gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz), 0.0);

    if (nl > 0.0)
      color += (diffuse * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * nl)
            +  (specular * gl_LightSource[0].specular * pow(max(dot(n, normalize(halfVector)), 0.0), shininess));

    gl_FragColor = color;
```

Where ambient, diffuse, specular, and shininess are all already defined.  `normal` and `halfv` are defined in my vertex shader as

```
normal         = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
halfv          = gl_LightSource[0].halfVector.xyz;
```

My light is directional, position is set to `100, 100, 100, 0`.  Ambient, diffuse, and specular values are `1, 1, 1, 1`, `.01, .01, .01, 1`, and `0, 0, 0, 1`, respectively.  When might light vector is `100, 100, 100, 0`, the entire mesh appears ambient lit.  Any other position or magnitude causes the mesh to go dark, only showing the ambient component.

**EDIT**

This is the updated fragment shader:

```
  vec4 color = ambient * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
  vec3 n = normalize(normal);
  vec3 ldir = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz);
  vec3 halfv = normalize(normalize(cam) + ldir);

  float nl = max(dot(n, ldir), 0.0);

  if (nl > 0.0)
    color += (diffuse * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * nl)
          +  (specular * gl_LightSource[0].specular * pow(max(dot(n, normalize(halfv)), 0.0), shininess));

  gl_FragColor = color;
```

and vertex shader:

```
normal         = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
cam            = camera_pos.xyz - gl_Vertex.xyz;
```

I'm still seeing a dark, ambient tone only.  I've also normalized my vector CPU side, now as `1, 1, 1, 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
dot(n, gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz)
```

The light vector needs to be normalized.  For a directional light, this can be precomputed as a unit vector pointing toward the light (note that directional lights don't have a position, only a direction).  For point lights you would subtract the light's position and the vertex position in the vertex shader, then normalize that in the pixel shader.

Similarly, the half-angle vector for specular lighting needs to be normalized, and it needs to be computed per-pixel based on the camera vector and the light vector at that pixel.  It can't be precomputed (except in the very special case of a parallel projection with a directional light).

Comment: How might I calculate the half vector?  What specific operations need to be applied?  How do I get the camera vector?  I am normalizing `halfv` in the fragment shader

Comment: The camera vector can be calculated as camera_pos - vertex_pos in the vertex shader, then sent down to the fragment shader and normalized.  Then the half vector is normalize(camera vector + light vector) where the camera and light vectors are both already normalized.

Comment: This is still not behaving; please see updated post

Comment: @user Check your colors.  You said in your post you set the diffuse color to (.01, .01, .01), which is very low; try something like (0.5, 0.5, 0.5).

Comment: I cranked it all the way to 1, 1, 1, 1... no change :(

Comment: It's time for you to start from the simplest shader and add one feature at a time until you find the problem.  Verify correct output at each step, etc...  Right now it feels like you're just throwing spaghetti at the wall to see what sticks =)

Comment: Well put.  What would be a good starting point?  Per-vertex directional shading?

Comment: @NathanReed Are you sure H cant be precomputed to implement a per-vertex Blinn-Phong shader? The fixed function pipelines of OpenGL&DX 9 used per-vertex Blinn-Phong shading, how it could be implemented without per-pixel operations? correct me if i'm wrong in my thoughts.

Comment: @Hernán It can be done per-vertex, but it's an approximation. It may look ok on finely tessellated models, not so great on low-poly ones.